# HTTPS Connection not working on Android app in Staging but working in Production

Tags: android, connection, ssl-certificate

HTTPS connections are no longer working on Staging.

They still work in Production.

We have an Android app deployed on Dev, Staging and Production.

We know that the TLS certificate in Staging was renewed on the third this month.

We don't do any certificate pinning on Staging.

We use OKHttp 3.14.2

```
    /*
      For more info on public key pinning see:
      https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning
     */
    CertificatePinner.Builder certificatePinnerBuilder = new CertificatePinner.Builder();

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        certificatePinnerBuilder.add(CERTIFICATE_PIN_PATTERN, CERTIFICATE_PIN);
    }

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .certificatePinner(certificatePinnerBuilder.build())
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> {
                return OkHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE.verify(hostname, session) || (!hostProvider.isProductionUrl());
            })
            .sslSocketFactory(socketFactory, trustManager)
            .build();
}
```

1 Connection. 0 byte sent. 0 byte received.

Comment: It's likely that the certificate that was updated for staging either has an issue - either a broken chain of trust, is self signed, expired (unlikely) etc...

Do you have a logcat from when you run this app while pointed to staging?

Comment: if you set up a try/catch block, you might catch the certificate error, and the error message might have more specific information in it.

Comment: Thanks. The certificate on staging is valid. It works on iOS. Just not on Android.

Comment: Additionally, this is the same box for Dev, Staging and Production...